# How do I use a certain remediation shell script in SCAP Workbench

Tags: openscap

I am new to SCAP Workbench and I am trying it out for the first time. I was wondering how do I use the remediation shell script for just one issue.

Answer (score 0):

For that case, I would recommend you to use the `oscap` tool to evaluate and opnionally fix one single rule. For example:

> sudo oscap xccdf eval --profile ospp --rule xccdf_org.ssgproject.content_rule_accounts_umask_interactive_users --results-arf /tmp/arf.xml --report /tmp/report.html --oval-results ssg-fedora-ds.xml

Note that in this command, besides informing the ospp profile (--profile), I also informed the specific rule (--rule). This command is not applying the remediation, but it could be achieved by including the `--remediate` option.